# Material UI Button - Align Ellipsis Label with Start Icon

Tags: reactjs, button, material-ui, ellipsis

I'm trying to set a start icon on a button and also the text label could be very long to use ellipsis at the end.
I can't figure it out a way to align the start icon and text at the same time while using ellipsis.

[image]

I've created a sandbox to show my example: [Button Ellipsis example](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-boyd-i4d2zm?file=/src/App.js)

How can I align the start icon and text so they are both in the same line?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add MuiButton-startIcon in the styles, I provide you the styles code snippet you can try and hope this can help you.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  button: {
    width: "220px",
    "& .MuiButton-label": {
      textOverflow: "ellipsis",
      whiteSpace: "nowrap",
      overflow: "hidden",
      display: "inline-block"
    },
    "& .MuiButton-startIcon": {
      display: 'inline-block'
    }
  }
}));
```

[image]